# I am trying to use the extracted variable data of one api in two other post api in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have extracted a variable called id from a get request which have multiple ID's data so I have used json extractor used the path $..id and match no as -1

Now I wanted to use this id data in other two post api urls in a 2 for each controller, (one controller for one api)

i have given input prifix as id and strat index 0 end index ${id_matchNr} and the output variable name as tug,

the 2 post url is something like [https://demo.qwe.com/red/{tug}](https://demo.qwe.com/red/%7Btug%7D)
[https://demo.qwe.com/blue/{tug}](https://demo.qwe.com/blue/%7Btug%7D)

I want to send 2 different values to these APIs for each iterations, but when I run it's taking same tug value for both the url paths for each iteration.

I tried giving both the post APIs in one foreach controller, still the same problem.

Please Help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) with the described configuration you will be able to refer the **current** value as `${tug}`

When it comes to the **next** value you need to calculate the incremented value of `${id_x}` JMeter Variable using current iteration of the ForEach Controller using [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) and use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) to evaluate the variable value.

Something like:

```
${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},2,)},)}
```

should do the trick for you.

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)